# Java Data in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

For a Java Programm where you type in Data that will be put into a PDF (The PDF already has Data in it, the data from the programm shall be put into specific places) . Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do a web search. Come back with more specific questions when you've tried something. Post your code. You may also want to take the tour of the site before posting.

Comment: The PDF already exists and data needs to be added "into specific places" sounds like you need the existing PDF to be an AcroForm and you want to fill out the AcroForm fields as described in the section **Filling out a Form** in this [iText 7 tutorial chapter](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-4-making-pdf-interactive).

Comment: Sarah, you should really clarify. Do you mean "filling in forms" when you say *"putting Data into a PDF into specific places"*? Which form technology is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [Itext PDF](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf) in maven project. You can add below function for printing data.

```
       private static String FILE = "../print2.pdf";   

    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
        document.open();            
         //This is title.
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        document.add(preface);
        preface.add(new Paragraph("This is cupcake.", catFont));
        addTitlePage(document);
        // This is content.
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor(AddSalesPromoController.tempPromoName.getText(), catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Chapter");
        document.close();
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File("../print2.pdf");
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ModelUtil.getAlert("Not supported", "not supported", Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                // no application registered for PDFs
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```